# Override Text Color Shiny Bootstrap

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, shiny

I have a shiny app that uses [boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/) and another custom JS package.  Right now when I add text with `p(` it comes out dark text color, which barely shows up on dark background.  I tried the `text-warning` color (which is like a yellow).  I'm looking for a simple text color override and so far nothing i've tried works.  Here is my code:

```
          p(class="text-warning", 'Size of dot = customer lane volume (will show visually)'),
          tags$head(tags$style(".text-warning{color: text-warning !important;}")) #this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the color as "text-warning", but text-warning is class (defined with particular color) not a valid color.
This should work:

```
p(class="text-warning", 'Size of dot = customer lane volume (will show visually)'),
          tags$head(tags$style(".text-warning{color: yellow !important;}"))
```

Comment: That's odd. Could you try style directly the paragraph?
p(style="color:yellow", 'Size of dot = customer lane volume (will show visually)')

Comment: Does it necessary has to be `text-warning` class? Could you create your own class? (Maybe there is some interference which is not obvious). When I use the code in the answer in the simple shiny app, it works.

Comment: i think create own class to handle this, as there is interference.  Suggestions on how to create that class?

Comment: `p(class="myclass", 'Size of dot = customer lane volume (will show visually)'),
          tags$head(tags$style(".myclass {color: yellow}"))`

Comment: Yeah, some interference is overriding that.  Frustrating.  Unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Could you share css files used? Does it behave the same in any browser?